# How do I send email with zipped attachment?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, zip, 7-zip, yahoo-mail

I'm zipping up a rather small folder, 243KB, containing Visual Studio project and solution files using 7zip or the Windows built-in Compressed (zipped folder) from the right click menu.

I've tried using Gmail, Outlook and Yahoo mail but none of them send my email with attachment.

Gmail does not show any error and the recipient confirms they never receive any email. Email without attachment is received successfully.

Outlook shows delivery failed email in my inbox,
Yahoo also shows mailer-demon error in my inbox.

I do not want to use Google Drive or Microsoft Onedrive.

My question is how do I send email with zipped attachments?

Comment: Have you tried sending it (or a similarly crafted email) to someone else? It sounds a lot like they have some kind of filtering or firewall blocking it.

Comment: What **exact** error message is received? You can obscure any sensitive parts of the message, but it would be good to know the error you get in order to narrow down the problem.

Comment: This might work: Try changing the file extension. Don't forget to give instructions to recipient to change the extension of the downloaded file into .zip again.

Comment: Some suggestions: gmail it to yourself to confirm the attachment doesn't go with the email; try removing any 'built' files (eg, the *.exe, ./build/debug) from the project/solution; try zipping all the files in the directory instead of the directory itself; what Els said; try emailing a different zip file as an attachment

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my own answer as I've tried cleaning my visual studio solution and it worked.

I removed the 'built' files exe (just cleaned my visual studio solution and it worked)